# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 74]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I want to apply LSTM.
I have 12 features and 74 rows

my data shape after dropping the targeted variable and reshape it for 3d arrays:(1, 74, 12)
and my targeted shape: (74,)
when I split the data using this code:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data_1, target, test_size = 0.2,random_state =25)
```

I got this error:

> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 74]

I defined the model well but when I fit the model also I have another error

defining the model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(1, batch_input_shape=(1, 74, 12), return_sequences = True))
model.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accurecy'])
model.summary()
```

fitting the model:

```
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 100, validation_data= (x_test, y_test))
```

here I have also this error:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_14 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 12)

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: can you share the entire traceback

Comment: Would you edit the question to add a succinct and meaningful title please?

Comment: I think you need to resample the data to `(74,1, 12)` instead of `(1, 74, 12)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.keras.layers.LSTM` expects inputs: A 3D tensor with shape `[batch, timesteps, feature]`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
inputs = tf.random.normal([32, 10, 8])
lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(4, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
whole_seq_output, final_memory_state, final_carry_state = lstm(inputs)
print(whole_seq_output.shape)
```

**Output**

```
(1, 74, 4)
```

If your input shape is of 2D, use `tf.expand_dims(input, axis=0)` to add extra dimension.